# Setting up angular project with Firebase auth login

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, authentication

I am trying to set up an angular project on visual studios with Firebase auth with standard email login. I have followed this tutorial ( https://www.codesolutionstuff.com/full-angular-13-firebase-authentication-tutorial-example/ ). I have gotten these errors.

```
    Error: ../../node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentSnapshotExists<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData | undefined'.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
  
../../node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
# #                                                ~
This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
# #   ../../node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
# #                                                ~
This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined` constraint.


Error: ../../node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.
```

I am new to angular and I have tired different tutorials. If anyone could even point me towards a different source that would be great. I have tried to search for the issue but I have not been able to find any solution